# Copy only selected values from one table to another table with condition

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I am trying to copy selected values from rows of one table to another table, the problem is that SQLite gives an error for a nested `SELECT` command as

`java.sql.SQLException: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression`

Here is what I am trying:

```
INSERT INTO table2(ID, ProjectName ) 
SELECT ID, ProjectName FROM table1
Where table1.ID NOT IN table2
```

I can't use `*` here, since  `table1` has four columns and `table2` has only 3.
All has to be done is to check if any `ID` value from `table1` is not present in `table2`, then copy only that `ID`, respective `ProjectName` values from `table1` and insert it into table2 as `ID, ProjectName , null`

null is for the thrid column value in table2.

Any suggestions or help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is almost there:

```
INSERT INTO table2(ID, ProjectName ) 
    SELECT ID, ProjectName
    FROM table1
    Where table1.ID NOT IN (select table2.id from table2);
```

This is standard SQL, so it should work in any database.

Comment: Bravo, worked like a charm. Didn't realize the last part, that I am supposed to select ID column from table2 as well. Such a stupid mistake :-D
Thanks a lot.